# If statement for multiples of an variable

Tags: c#, if-statement

I know how to construct if statements that can take multiple conditions.

```
if ((condition1) || (condition2) || (conditionN))
    statements;
```

And I want to simply the expression I have at the moment.

```
if ((gameScore == 480) || (gameScore == 960) || (gameScore == 1440))
```

Basically I want to have a if statement or something similar the will execute code when gameScore is equal to any multiple of 480.

Comment: you want the `%` operator - [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx). `if(gameScore % 480 == 0)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the modulus (%) operator which is similar to division (/) but returns the remainder of the operation instead of the quotient. The remainder will be 0 after dividing by 480 if the number is a multiple of 480.

```
if ((gameScore % 480) == 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well if you only need to check multiples of 480, use a modulus-based check.

```
if (gameScore % 480 == 0) {}
```

To answer your first question, a switch statement is another option for combining if-statements for certain circumstances.  So in this example, you could do something like

```
switch (number)
{
    // A switch section can have more than one case label. 
    case 480:
    case 960:
    case 1440:
        //do stuff for these three cases
    default:
        //else
        break;
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx for more on switch statements in C#.